# Cygwin use urxvt as shell and w3m-img not working with neofetch / ranger

Tags: windows, cygwin, urxvt, w3m

So I'm trying to use urxvt instead of mintty but I haven't found a way other than launching mintty then launching urxvt and closing mintty.
I tried making another .bat file which launched cmd.exe and then urxvt, but I can't close cmd.exe

My other issue is that w3m-img doesn't work with ranger or neofetch. if I use `w3m pic.jpg` it opens the picture in a new widow and doesn't display it inline like it should

If anyone has any experience with this I would like some help

Comment: One problem and one question, please. Urxvt and mintty are not shell but terminals; urxvt requires X and mintty don't use X. so please clarify what are you doing and what is the problem.

Comment: My apologies, I have an X server running so that's not an issue. I am trying to launch urxvt without going into mintty first and without having a cmd.exe hanging around

Answer (score 0):

You can run urxvt from the the XDG menu that have all the applications or from the Xserver menu

[image: Xserver Menu]

To customize the X menu:

```
cp /etc/defaults/etc/X11/system.XWinrc ~/.XWinrc
```

add in ~/.XWinrc a new urxvt row to the menu

```
menu apps {
        xterm   exec    "xterm"
        urxvt   exec    "urxvt"
        notepad exec    notepad
        xload   exec    "xload -display %display%"  # Comment
}
```